# Data models dependencies, can I simplify these objects?

Tags: python, django

Essentially I have 6 object models, 3 for my regular objects and 3 for the dependencies of those objects. Individually, these objects can be dependent on one or multiple instances of each of the 3 regular objects.

**My Question:**
Is this best practice? I essentially want to be able to add a new dependency to a regular object when needed. For example:

```
a = A.objects.get(id=1)
adependency = ADependencies.objects.get(dependentTo=a)
```

Then, I'd have an object with all of the dependencies for `a`.

---

Alternatively, I did think of a way to merge the 3 dependency objects into one; however, I'm unsure whether it's good practice.

```
class Dependencies(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    dependentTo = CharField(max_length=16)
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
    b = models.ManyToManyField(B)
    c = models.ManyToManyField(C)
```

In this scenario, I don't use a ForeignKey to map the dependentTo object. Instead, I would use the object id to pull the object - allowing me to be class agnostic; however, this would require unique ids throughout the 3 regular objects.

```
a = A.objects.get(id=1)
adependency = ADependencies.objects.get(dependentTo=a.id)
```

---

**One more idea!**
Is it possibly to still use ForeignKey's, but pass in a string with the class name instead?

```
class Dependencies(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    dependentTo = ForeignKey(type)
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
    b = models.ManyToManyField(B)
    c = models.ManyToManyField(C)
```

---

Object Models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class B(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

class C(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)

class ADependencies(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    dependentTo = models.ForeignKey(A)
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
    b = models.ManyToManyField(B)
    c = models.ManyToManyField(C)

class BDependencies(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    dependentTo = models.ForeignKey(B)
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
    b = models.ManyToManyField(B)
    c = models.ManyToManyField(C)

class CDependencies(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    dependentTo = models.ForeignKey(B)
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
    b = models.ManyToManyField(B)
    c = models.ManyToManyField(C)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done a lot simpler.  Define a `Dependency` model instead of a `Dependencies` model.  You will need the [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) django contribution:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Dependency(models.Model):
    dependent_contenttype = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    dependent_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    dependent = GenericForeignKey('dependent_contenttype', 'dependent_id')

    prerequisite_contenttype = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    prerequisite_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    prerequisite = GenericForeignKey('prerequisite_contenttype', 
                                     'prerequisite_id')
```

Then you can make dependencies a reverse generic relation on models `A`, `B` and `C` if you like:

```
class A:
    # ...
    dependencies = GenericRelation(
        Dependency,
        content_type_field='dependent_contenttype',
        object_id_field='dependent_id')
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I think inheritance may simplify your data structures a lot.

Let's leave model `A` as-is:

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Your classes `B` and `C` has those fields of `A` plus one additional, so we may rewrite that as

```
class B(A):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

class C(A):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

Now as we have one base class, we only need one dependency class:

```
class ADependencies(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    dependentTo = models.ForeignKey(A)
    dependents = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

Now you can set any of `A`, `B` and `C` objects to `dependentTo` and `dependents`. If you only need the main object from dependency, the object of type `A` will have either attribute `b`, attribute `c` or none of them. You may also query on those attributes:

```
ADependencies.objects.filter(dependentTo__b__isnull=False)
```

This structure is more scalable and more easily maintainable because if you need to add one more model, you only need to write the unique code for it and don't have to deal with dependency classes.

One more way to simplify your models is to just have one model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True)
```

This way you only have model `A` and you may leave field `a` empty (indication that it is just a simple `A` instance) or set the value of `a` (it will mean the object of type `B` or `C`). Then your dependency class is the same as in previous example, but you don't need to deal with those backwards relations to test for true object type.

If you really need to disinguish between `B` and `C` objects you may write your `A` class like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    A = 0
    B = 1
    C = 2
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (A, "A"),
        (B, "B"),
        (C, "C")
    )
    id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True)
    obj_type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

This way you have just one model class and one dependency class and can tell what type the object is by checking `obj_type`. Also you should implement some check to prevent cases where `a` is not `null` and `obj_type` is A and similar.

Let me know if this solution is what you need.